# Context Parameter missing in discordpy bot

Tags: python, discord.py, runtime-error

I am just starting with Discord.py and am having the following Error Note:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 976, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Entropy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 693, in _parse_arguments
    raise discord.ClientException(fmt.format(self))
discord.errors.ClientException: Callback for ping command is missing "ctx" parameter.
```

The error message is given anytime i typed .hello, .ping or .close into Discord

This is the main file:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from botclass import *

#esc = True
load_dotenv()
tken = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents =intents)
client.load_extension('botclass')
print('\n'+tken+'\n')
client.run(tken)
```

And this is the file that holds the commands you can give

```
from attr import attributes
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class DaCommands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.command(name='hello',pass_context=True)
    async def hello(ctx):
        await ctx.reply('hello')

    @commands.command(name="ping",pass_context=True)
    async def ping(ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send(f'ping! ' + str(round(commands.latency * 1000)) + 'ms')

    @commands.command(name='close',pass_context=True)
    async def exits(ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send('Closed')
        await quit()

def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    client.add_cog(DaCommands(client))
```

Thanks for solving my problem in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are missing self from the command methods

```
async def hello(self, ctx: commands.Context):
```

This is basic OOP / class functionality you should know and understand when using bots.

Also do not import your cog manually using

```
from botclass import *
```

This pollutes the namespace and is unnecessary. There are the odd exception to this, such as using `__all__` dunder but that is a whole other matter and irrelevant to this.

You should use a lib, such as pathlib, to grab the files in the directory you save your bot extensions and then load them using
`await bot.load_extension(file)`
As would be `async def setup()` in your extensions / cogs

Note this is async in dpy 2.x

`pass_context=True` is extremely old and obsolete code that is no longer needed.

I can only assume you are following a very outdated online tutorial. I recommend you look at the examples on the offical dpy github repo, their docs and join the discord for further help.

Comment: well thank you, and i am still a learner and i learn with every line